# Probability that $B_4>1$ given $B_2=B_5=0$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, solution-verification, brownian-motion

I'm trying to find an answer to the following question:

> A standard Brownian motion crosses the $t$-axis at times $t=2$ and $t=5$. Find the probability that the process exceeds level $x=1$ at time $t=4$.

If I understood correctly the exercise is asking for

$$
\Pr [B_4>1|B_2=0,B_5=0]\tag1
$$

where $B_t$ is an standard Brownian motion. It seems weird to ask for a probability conditioned to an event of probability zero, so I'm not sure if I have the correct interpretation of the exercise. Other than that what I did is the following: because $B_2=0$ then the process given by $\tilde B_{t-2}:=B_t-B_2$, for $t\geqslant 2$, is also an standard Brownian motion, and we have that (1) is equivalent to

$$
\Pr [\tilde B_2>1|\tilde B_3=0]\tag2
$$
as $\tilde B_2$ is independent of $B_2$ (however it seem weird to talk about independence of events of zero probability). Now, its also known that the process defined by $X_t:=t\tilde B_{1/t}$, with $X_0:\equiv 0$, is also an standard Brownian motion, so its easy to check that (2) is equivalent to

$$
\Pr [X_{1/6}>1/2]\approx 0.110336\tag3
$$

My questions: its this solution correct, or its just senseless? There is a different way to interpret the exercise?

---

UPDATE: it can be shown that the result above coincide with the result if we use a Brownian bridge formulation. It seems that the continuity of the paths of the Brownian motion give the possibility to define, consistently, conditional probabilities over events of zero probability.

Comment: "It seems weird to ask for a probability conditioned to an event of probability zero" - Then does it make sense that $\operatorname{Pr}[B_4>1\mid B_2, B_5] = f(B_2,B_5)$ allows you to evaluate $f(0,0)$?  I think that's the formal interpretation. (Note here $f$ is continuous, so there's no problem with evaluation)

Comment: @Brian right, but there are infinitely many conditional probability distributions, as $f$ is a class of a.s. functions. However it seems, in this case, possible to pin someone using some regularity of the Brownian motion. But the more easy to handle interpretation for this case is using a Brownian bridge, then there is no need to see weird things (I was unaware of this way to proceed)

Comment: Conditioning on an event of probability isn't strange at all, I claim; the only thing about it is that one can't use Bayes's formula. But everything having to do with continuous probabilities deals with events of probability 0, so we shouldn't shy away from them.

Comment: @Greg I know, but as I said in my previous comment a conditional probability is a class of functions that are equal almost sure, so for a specific event of zero probability in general is meaningless to give it a probability. However in the case of a Brownian motion seems plausible to give a specific value to any conditioned event due to the continuity of the Brownian paths